# Curl failed: NSS: client certificate not found (nickname not specified) - On Centos 7

Tags: php, curl, openssl, centos7, nss

I know this has been asked on SO before but I think my situation is a little bit different:

When I'm trying to use curl inside PHP I receive the following error when trying to interact with apples push notification service (https://api.push.apple.com/3/device/)

```
Curl failed: NSS: client certificate not found (nickname not specified)
```

This is due to the fact that on centos, php is build with curl that uses NSS instead OpenSSL.

What I tried so far:

- Recompiling curl (worked! Binary is able to perform the call, but php is not)
- Recompiling php (didnt work, as it requires curl-devel to be installed, which might link to NSS again)

So my next approach is to fix this NSS problem, but it turns out NSS is a very bad piece of software as just a simple rename of an imported lets-ecnrypt certificate doesnt work.. ..

Could someone *please* explain me how I could fix this? I already tried importing a lets encrypt certificate into the NSS database stored in /etc/pki/nssdb, that worked - but unfortunately the certificate is not recognized in PHP, even if I provide its nickname in CURLOPT_SSLCERT => 'nickname'.

Maybe this is because it has special characters inside its nickname which i cannot change as NSS fails to rename (lol).

When I directly try to provide certificates in php using

```
CURLOPT_SSLCERT => $certFile,
CURLOPT_SSLKEY => $keyFile,
CURLOPT_CAINFO => $caCertFile
```

I get:

```
 Curl failed: Peer's Certificate issuer is not recognized.
```

I also turned of peer verification by

`CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => FALSE`

ending in

```
 Curl failed: security library failure
```

Is there anybody out there who could teach me how to fix it or how to build php on centos with builting curl using openssl?

BR,

Comment: I don't have a solution to your exact problem, but one potential work around is to use the binary that you compiled that works and just shell out to that with something like `proc_open`. It is hacky, I know, but at least you can move forward

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got this working, here is what I did:

1. Recompiled curl with openssl and put the libcurl.so.4 in a new folder /home/mylibs/
2. Copied all libs from /usr/lib to /home/mylibs/ while not replacing my libcurl.so.4
3. Located the system's php-cgi binary, renamed it to php-cgi-real
4. Created a blank file php-cgi

```
#! /bin/bash
export LD_PRELOAD=/home/mylibs/libcurl.so.4
exec php-cgi-real "$@"
```

5. Restarted the service
6. Done!